# Transparent Navbar Not Working on Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I am having a problem with a navbar in chrome.  I'm using `bootstrap`, but the transparency is via custom CSS not through `bootstrap`'s `transparent` class.

Here's the erb for the navbar:

```
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">The Manly Art of BBQ</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to 'Man Rules', home_site_rules_path, class:"waves-effect waves-light" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'BBQ', home_bbq_path, class:"waves-effect waves-light" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'My Mancard', root_path, class:"waves-effect waves-light" %></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- collapse -->
  </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
</div> <!-- custom-bootstrap-menu -->
```

And an example of what comes below it on my `index` page:

```
<div class="hero-image-row">
  <div class="hero-image-outer text-center">
    <div class="hero-image-inner text-center">
      <%= image_tag 'Background 1.jpg', class: "hero-image",alt: "Delicious-looking hot dogs on a manly grill. Just like God intended." %>
    </div> <!-- hero-image-inner -->
  </div> <!-- hero-image-inner -->
</div> <!-- row -->
```

Here's my custom CSS for the navbar, SASS variables included.

SASS Variables:

```
 $transparent-black: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 $transparent-white: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);
```

And the actual CSS:
    /* NAVIGATION */

```
 #custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar {
   margin-bottom: 0px !important;
 }

 #custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: black;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: $font-typewriter;
    background-color: $transparent-white !important;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: black;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: black;
    background-color: $transparent-black !important;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: black;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: $transparent-black;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: $transparent-black;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: black !important; /* Change border color around this buttons */
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background: black !important; /* Change color for horizontal lines */
}
```

And for the content below:

```
/* HEROS */

.hero-image-row {
   overflow-x: hidden !important;
   width: 100% !important;
   margin-top: -50px !important;
   -webkit-margin-before: -50px !important;
 }

.hero-image-outer {
   width: 300%;
   height: 400px;
   overflow-y: hidden !important;
 }

 .hero-image-inner {
   width: 66%;
   overflow: hidden !important;
 }

 .hero-image {
   height: 400px;
   margin-left: -50%;
   z-index: 0 !important;
 }

 @media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
   .hero-image-outer {
     width: 100%;
   }

   .hero-image-inner {
     width: 100%;
     height: 400px;
   }

   .hero-image {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     margin-left: 0%;
   }
 }
```

The transparency works perfectly on IE, but in Chrome the `margin-top: -50px !important' doesn't appear, which makes the navbar appear white.

If I apply the `margin-top` and the accompanying `webkit-margin` line to the `.hero-image-outer` class instead of `.hero-image-row` the margin is applied, but the transparency still doesn't work, so it still appears as a white navbar (you can tell it moved up by looking at the image).

Can anyone familiar with Chrome help me fix this?

Comment: You should post your complied CSS output because there's no way of knowing what the values of your variables should be so it's not possible to see the issue.

Comment: @vanburen, thank you for noticing that!  I added the SASS variables to the original post.  Do you think SASS could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're referring to: you're seeing the `body` color (white) behind the transparent `navbar` and not the hero image. You *could* technically change the `.hero-image-row` div to `display:inline-block` but this ultimately only reveals another new issue. Because the navbar and hero image have default positioning you'll see the mobile toggle menu push the image down when it's opened which probably isn't a desirable feature.

Another option is to restructure the entire hero image HTML because all the overflow hidden rules are also an issue when it comes to moving your nested image with negative margins.

Probably the easiest thing to do is apply `position:absolute` to your `navbar` to remove it from the flow all together.

```
#custom-bootstrap-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lekton:400,400italic,700);
 #custom-bootstrap-menu {
  font-family: "Lekton";
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu .navbar-nav > li > a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu .navbar-brand {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: black;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: black;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu .navbar-toggle:focus,
#custom-bootstrap-menu .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: black;
}
.hero-image-row {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.hero-image-outer {
  width: 300%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.hero-image-inner {
  width: 66%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hero-image {
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: -50%;
  z-index: 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .hero-image-outer {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .hero-image-inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
  }
  .hero-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #custom-bootstrap-menu .navbar-collapse {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">The Manly Art of BBQ</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light">Man Rules </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light">BBQ </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light">My Mancard </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="hero-image-row">
  <div class="hero-image-outer text-center">
    <div class="hero-image-inner text-center">
      <img src="http://www.mybudgettrip.com/south-goa-beaches/slides/03.jpg" class="hero-image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>1 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I can't believe it was something that simple.

Answer (score 0):

add a class opaque-navbar to the div whose id is "custom-bootstrap-menu" and write its css as:-

`.opaque-navbar{
             background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        }`